# C# Free Image file from use

Tags: c#, image, bmp

i have a temp image file which i open with

```
Bitmap CapturedImg = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile("Item/Item.bmp");
```

and because is temp i want to replace it with another image for further use, but the program still using that image and i cannot do anything.

How to let go from the image in order to be replaced?

Comment: Bitmap CapturedImg = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile("Item/NewItem.bmp");

Comment: Try o Save & Dispose the CapturedImg before replacing it with new one

Comment: if your adding it to a picturebox after you loaded the image try PictureBox1.Refresh();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem and could not use using, since the file was overwritten by some asynchronous code. I solved the issue by making a copy of the Bitmap and freeing the original one:

```
                Bitmap tmpBmp = new Bitmap(fullfilename);
                Bitmap image= new Bitmap(tmpBmp);
                tmpBmp.Dispose();
```

Comment: I think it could be easier `Bitmap image = new Bitmap(fullfilename).Clone();`

Answer (score 3):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4sahykhd.aspx)

> The file remains locked until the Image is disposed.

Read Image from File Stream Instead

```
using( FileStream stream = new FileStream( path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read ) )
{
         image = Image.FromStream( stream );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this syntax

```
using (Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile("Item/Item.bmp"))
{
    // Do here everything you need with the image
}
// Exiting the block, image will be disposed
// so you should be free to delete or replace it
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using (var stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead("Item\Item.bmp"))
{
    var image= (Bitmap)System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this.

```
 BitmapImage bmpImage= new BitmapImage();
 bmpImage.BeginInit();
 Uri uri = new Uri(fileLocation);
 bmpImage.UriSource = uri;
 bmpImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
 bmpImage.EndInit();
 return bmpImage;
```

Answer (score 0):

This like:

```
public Bitmap OpenImage(string filePath) =>
    return new Bitmap(filePath).Clone();
```

Or this like:

```
public Bitmap OpenImage(string filePath)
{
    using (Bitmap tmpBmp = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(filePath))
    {
        return new Bitmap(tmpBmp);
    }
}
```

Or this like:

```
public Bitmap OpenImage(string filePath)
{
    using (var stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(filePath))
    {
        return (Bitmap)System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
    }
}
```